# Why @Scheduled and <task:scheduled ../> behave differently for dependencies injection in Spring 3.0?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, scheduled-tasks

Same question was asked by someone but not answered properly.

If I am using annotation code inside scheduled method is interacting with injected objects but not working in case of  in xml.

Comment: Do you have <mvc:annotation-driven> in your `root-context`..?

Comment: yes annotation is working. But xml is not working do i need <mvc:annotation-driven>  in xml configuration too???

Comment: No. If you are using XML, you need to remove this tag.

Comment: I have already removed it in case of xml, still facing problem